# How to use multiple azure managed service identity in Terraform provider

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure

I have two subscriptions and a VM in my Azure account. I have assigned two Service Identities to the VM where each MSI is assigned with one subscription. I want my terraform script to use both of them in my providers block. How to proceed with this situation.

I tried to provide client id of the MSI within the provider block but terraform somewhat considers 1 MSI as default and goes along with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can define [multiple providers](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/providers.html#alias-multiple-provider-instances) in the terraform script, then use the MSI authenticate. And you can choose which provider to use with the `provider` property when you create the resources.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I posted this question after trying multiple providers. It just takes a default msi and executes the code

Comment: @Anbu It seems the MSI authenticate just can be used inside the VM which the MSI belongs to. So I would suggest you use the service principal. It can be used outside the VM and for different subscriptions.

Comment: I knew that the service principal could be used outside my VM. But my requirement was to maintain a token service so that we don't need to rotate the service principal's secret regularly rather than that if we use msi azure takes care of rotating secrets.

Comment: @Anbu It seems impossible. The MSI of the VM just can be used inside the VM and one VM just have one MSI. So you cannot use multiple MSI inside one VM.

Comment: Azure provides multiple MSI association with the VM. So I thought of exploring its purposes

Comment: @Anbu It's a misunderstanding. The MSI just control the permission to manage the VM. Only the system identity of the VM you can use to manage other services inside the VM. And the MSI in the terraform means the system identity of the VM.

Comment: What exactly happens when I associate multiple user-assigned service identity to a VM.

Comment: @Anbu Then you need to use the service principal authentication in the terraform.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your responses